# AWS - Strongswan :: How to make clients from subnets communicate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

I have successfully setup an IPsec VPN between 2 VPCs from 2 different regions via Strongswan and the 2 gateways are able to connect.
The problem is that the other instances of a vpc/subnets are not able to ping the other vpc/subnet: 
VPC A/gateway can talk to VPC B/gateway... 
VPC A/Instance can talk to VPC A/Gateway
Same applies for VPC B... But
VPC A / Instance can NOT talk to VPC B/Gateway B or VPC B/ Instances ( Same applies for VPC B to VPC A).

I have checked and tried to play with the routes of table 220 and also ICMP redirects, no way.

Anyone can assist please?

Regards.

Comment: I would suggest to enable VPC flow logs in both VPCs. That will help you with the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4):

There is way too little information to provide an exact answer; topology and addressing plan, relevant security groups and EC2 configuration, StrongSwan and relevant Linux kernel configuration would be needed.

Still please let me offer a few hints what to do in order to allow routing among subnets connected via VPN:

1. IP forwarding must be enabled in Linux kernel, assuming the StrongSwan runs on Linux EC2 instance. It can be done with following command, run as root:
   `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
   Please note that the setting would not persist during a reboot. How to make the setting persistent depends on the Linux distribution.
2. EC2 source/dest. check must be disabled, see the screenshot below.
   [image: EC2 source/dest. check]
3. VPC routing tables must be set to route the traffic to the another subnet in another region via the StrongSwan EC2 node, instead of via default gateway.
4. Traffic selectors (`left_subnet` and `right_subnet`) in `ipsec.conf` must be set accordingly.

Comment: Hi, Point3/ Can you please clarify? I have set it not to default gateway but to new gtw that was previously attached to my VPC. - As per your suggestion i Tried to set it to the IP adress of the EC2 instance but not accepting. Can you please clarify how I should do this?