# [strongswan][site2site][vpn] s2s is working, but hosts in net A are not able to reach hosts in net B

Tags: routes, vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I established a site to site VPN with strongswan. We have the following setup:

NET A - VPN Gate A - VPN Gate B - NET B

Lets assume:
NET A is 10.2.0.0/24
NET B is 172.18.0.0/24

VPN Gate A is able to reach hosts in NET B.
VPN Gate A has an IP 10.2.0.4 belonging to NET A

NET A contains a host, lets call it host 1, 10.2.0.2
NET B contains a host lets call it host 2, 172.18.0.33

**VPN Gate**

**/etc/swanctl/conf.d/site2site.conf**

```
connections {
   foo-bar {
      local_addrs  = GATE A
      remote_addrs = GATE B

      local {
         auth = psk
         id = GATE A
      }
      remote {
         auth = psk
         id = GATE B
      }
      children {
         net-net {
            local_ts  = 10.2.0.0/24
            remote_ts = 172.18.0.0/24

            rekey_time = 90m
            esp_proposals = aes256-sha384-modp4096
            start_action=start
         }
      }
      version = 2
      mobike = no
      keyingtries=0
      reauth_time =0s
      proposals = aes256-sha384-modp4096
   }
}

secrets {
   ike-1 {
      id-1a = GATE A
      id-1b = GATE B
      secret = ****
   }
}
```

**IPTABLES**

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  172.18.0.0/24        10.2.0.0/24          policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 1 proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  10.2.0.0/24          172.18.0.0/24        policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 1 proto esp
```

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
```

**Host 1**

To allow host 1 to communicate with host 2 I tried to establish a route:

```
ip route add  10.2.0.4/32 dev enp8s0
ip route add 172.18.0.0/24 via 10.2.0.4
```

Existing routes before:

```
ip route

default via xxx dev eth0
10.2.0.0/24 via 10.2.0.1 dev enp8s0
10.2.0.1 dev enp8s0 scope link
xxx dev eth0 scope link
```

Before adding the routes I am able to ping the address of the VPN GATE A, afterwards I am no more.

Where is my fault?

Comment: There is not enough information. Please share your strongswan and Linux config. Also, you may want to view my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223611/4806599

Comment: @GoodMirek I hope I added the missing information